# Angular - limit the function calls from a <form> when pressing on "submit" button to one call

Tags: html, angular, forms

After pressing the submit button, the button don't become disabled.
And I can activate the submit function number of times.

I want to make the function to be able call only once.
Is there a way to limit the function calls to one time or to disable the button after one click?
Also, my button disappear after pressing (it take a few seconds, so you can press it again) so i don't care if the button will stay disabled.

my application is in angular 5, and i'm not allowed to use pure JavaScript or JQuery.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="okButtonClick()">   
<button *ngIf="!isDuplicateCalendar" type="submit" autofocus containerClass="popover-small" [popover]="isValidAddCalendar()" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
          class="d-button d-button_primary"  [translate]="'add'" [disabled]="isClicked"></button>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is mark some fields as required, on button click you can do something as the code bellow:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="okButtonClick()">   
<button *ngIf="!isDuplicateCalendar" type="submit" autofocus containerClass="popover-small" [popover]="isValidAddCalendar()" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
          class="d-button d-button_primary"  [translate]="'add'" [disabled]="!form.isValid"></button>
</form>

okButtonClick(){
    //sending form data to backend using HTTP request
    this.form.reset()
 }
```

Comment: very creative idea thanks! but it also don't work. because i'm waiting for my http response to return (done by rxjs observable) and until it finished you can still press on the button

Answer (score 0):

declare variable in ts

```
isClicked=false;

    okButtonClick(){
      this.isClicked =true;
     }
```

Comment: this is what i did and it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: what's happening with your case beccz it 's should work